# Android 4.2.2+ Hotspot

Tags: android, shell

I hooked into the /system/bin/netd binary to log all of the commands that are sent by the Android framework when it puts up a hotspot via clicking buttons in the system settings menu. (I needed to be able to bring up the hotspot up from shell & ADB without bringing up the settings menu.)

This returned all of the commands that are used to put up the hotspot.

```
    interface clearaddrs wlan0 
    interface ipv6 wlan0 disable 
    resolver flushif wlan0 
    bandwidth setglobalalert 2097152 
    bandwidth setglobalalert 2097152 
    softap fwreload wlan0 AP 
    softap set wlan0 asdfa wpa2-psk 12345678 
    softap startap 
    interface getcfg wlan0 
    interface setcfg wlan0 192.168.43.1 24 running multicast broadcast up 
    tether interface add wlan0 
    ipfwd enable 
    tether start 192.168.42.2 192.168.42.254 192.168.43.2 192.168.43.254 192.168.44.2 192.168.44.254 192.168.45.2 192.168.45.254 192.168.46.2 192.168.46.254 192.168.47.2 192.168.47.254 192.168.48.2 192.168.48.254 
    tether dns set 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Seems OK.

When I issue those commands through /system/bin/ndc from shell, nothing returns an error and claims that it succeeded. Great. Fantastic. Wonderful.

```
    200 0 Interface IP addresses cleared
    200 0 IPv6 state changed
    200 0 Resolver command succeeded
    200 0 Bandwidth command succeeeded
    200 0 Bandwidth command succeeeded
    200 0 Softap operation succeeded
    200 0 Softap operation succeeded
    600 Iface linkstate wlan0 down
    600 Iface linkstate wlan0 down
    200 0 Softap operation succeeded
    213 0 44:33:4c:3d:98:dc 0.0.0.0 0 down broadcast multicast
    200 0 Interface configuration set
    200 0 Tether operation succeeded
    200 0 ipfwd operation succeeded
    200 0 Tether operation succeeded
    200 0 Tether operation succeeded
```

Super! Except for the little trivial fact that the hotspot cannot be seen afterwards and it doesn't even kick me off the wireless connection, so obviously I am missing something.

It might be useful to note that in Android 4.1.1 the following works (as expected), but in 4.2.2 it does not; I have tried endless combinations of the logged commands and the 4.1.1 commands to very little avail.

```
    softap stopap
    softap stop wlan0
    softap fwreload ap0 AP
    softap start wlan0 
    softap set wlan0 ap0 SSID wpa2-psk 12345678 11 0 8
    softap startap
    interface setcfg ap0 192.168.2.254 255.255.255.0 up
```

Here is what happens when the hotspot is taken down via the system settings menu, maybe it will be helpful:

```
    interface getcfg wlan0 
    interface setcfg wlan0 0.0.0.0 0 running multicast broadcast up 
    tether interface remove wlan0 
    tether stop 
    ipfwd disable 
    softap stopap 
    softap fwreload wlan0 STA 
    softap fwreload wlan0 STA 
    interface getcfg wlan0 
    interface setcfg wlan0 0.0.0.0 0 multicast broadcast down 
    interface ipv6privacyextensions wlan0 enable 
    interface getcfg p2p0 
    interface setcfg p2p0 0.0.0.0 0 multicast broadcast up 
    interface ipv6 wlan0 enable 
    interface route add wlan0 default 192.168.2.254 32 0.0.0.0 
    interface route add wlan0 default 0.0.0.0 0 192.168.2.254 
    resolver flushif wlan0 
    interface route add wlan0 default 192.168.2.254 32 0.0.0.0 
    bandwidth setglobalalert 2097152 
    interface route add wlan0 default 0.0.0.0 0 192.168.2.254 
    bandwidth setglobalalert 2097152
```

This is what is logged during system startup before any user input is possible:

```
    interface list 
    interface getcfg eth0 
    interface ipv6 wlan0 disable 
    interface list 
    bandwidth enable 
    softap fwreload wlan0 STA 
    firewall disable 
    interface getcfg wlan0 
    interface setcfg wlan0 0.0.0.0 0 multicast broadcast down 
    interface ipv6privacyextensions wlan0 enable 
    bandwidth setglobalalert 2097152 
    firewall disable 
    interface setthrottle rmnet0 -1 -1 
    interface getcfg p2p0 
    interface setcfg p2p0 0.0.0.0 0 multicast broadcast up 
    interface ipv6 wlan0 enable 
    resolver setifdns wlan0 192.168.2.254 
    resolver setdefaultif wlan0 
    interface route add wlan0 default 192.168.2.254 32 0.0.0.0 
    interface route add wlan0 default 0.0.0.0 0 192.168.2.254 
    resolver flushif wlan0 
    interface route add wlan0 default 192.168.2.254 32 0.0.0.0 
    interface route add wlan0 default 0.0.0.0 0 192.168.2.254
```

The only thing I do know for sure is that I can trigger the hotspot to come up in 4.4.3 when I issue commands to netd prior to the bootanimation completion.

Where did I go wrong?